# Iterating through multiple text files and comparing

Tags: python, list, file, iteration

I'm trying to write a function that puts text files into a list and then iterates through the files to find exact and partial copies to weed out people who may have cheated by plagarising their work. I start by using my class roster and adding .txt to their name to find their assignments and whether they've even completed the assignment or not. I have over 500 students' papers to read. With the code i've written so far it is literally iterating word by word within the .txt files so I'm getting WAY TOO many "cheated"s back.  PLEASE HELP.

```
def Cheaters():
    file = open("roster.txt", "r")
    L = []
    for i in file:
        new = [i[:-1], ".txt"]
        new2 = "".join(new)
        if i not in L:
            L.append(new2)
    for j in L:
        try:
            file2 = open(j, "r")
            for n in file2:
                for m in file2:
                    if n == m:
                        print("Cheated")
        except:
            print("No work submitted")
```

Comment: The first thing is to define what constitutes cheating.  Finding matched words or pairs of words is a poor metric because these are likely to be quite common within a given topic.  You may want to break each document up by sentence and compare how many sentences are shared between documents.  If you wanted to get really clever, you could implement an edit distance that compares how many replacements it takes to get from each sentence in one document to each sentence in another document.

Comment: Thank you. I want to check for partial or all out plagarism. Could you please explain how I could iterate line by line instead of word by word? Also what exactly do you mean by "edit distance?" such as a range of elements able to be edited?

Comment: I am working on a some code to help you out.  Are all of the document file names in a list in roster.txt?

Comment: roster is literally just names that's why I wrote the code to add .txt to add to the names in order to put the files into a list...Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  You may need to modify it for your file structure, but it should be close.

```
import re
from itertools import product

def hash_sentences(document):
    # remove all characters except those below, replace with a space
    # split into a list
    cleaned_text = re.sub(r'[^A-z0-9,;:\.\?! ]', ' ', document)
    sentences = re.split(r'[\?.!\.]', cleaned_text)

    # the less than 5 removes short sentences like "Dr."
    # return a hash of the sentences for comparison
    return [hash(s.strip().lower()) for s in sentences if len(s) > 5]  

def compare_documents(doc1, doc2):
    hash1 = hash_sentences(doc1)
    hash2 = hash_sentences(doc2)
    # return the percentage of sentences of doc1 that are in doc2
    return sum((h in hash2) for h in hash1) / float(len(hash1))

# get list of document file names
with open('roster.txt', 'r') as fp:
    doc_fnames = [d+'.txt' for d in fp.readlines()]

# create dictionay of file names and content
doc_dict = {}
for fname in doc_fnames:
    try:
        with open(fname, 'r') as fp:
            doc_dict[fname] = fp.read()
    except:
        print('No submission: %s' %fname)

# iterate through the pairs of documents
for doc_pair in product(doc_dict.keys(), doc_dict.keys()):
    pct = compare_documents(doc_dict[doc_pair[0]], doc_dict[doc_pair[1]])
    print('Percentage of %s sentences in %s: %0.2f%%' %(doc_pair[0], doc_pair[1], 100*pct))
```